# Filter out all rows preceding a string match

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to get `DataFrame` to *discard all rows that precedes* the place where there is a string match in one of the columns.

In other words: The row with the string match, and all rows after it, should be kept. (Column headers should also be kept).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

test_string = "myUniqueMatch"    
found_match = df["Column"].str.contains(test_string).sum()

if found_match == 1:
    match_location = df[df["Column"].str.contains(test_string)].index.tolist()
    df = df.iloc[match_location]
```

My probably superfluous code above will find the index location of the first match (assuming there is only one possible match).

The last line of code is a placeholder. I would here like to get all rows including and following `match_location`. How?

Ideally, if there are multiple matches, the first row to be kept is where the first match occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just select starting with the first match, you could just pick the first matching `index` and `slice` accordingly - the below does not depend on the index value in case the `index` is non-unique:

```
df.iloc[df['strings'].tolist().index(test_string):]
```

The fix for your code would also simply be to use [`slicing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges):

```
df = df.iloc[match_location:]
```

The above is quick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'), 100), columns=['strings'])
test_string = 'A'

%timeit df.iloc[df['strings'].tolist().index(test_string):]
10000 loops, best of 3: 95 µs per loop

%timeit df.iloc[np.flatnonzero(df['strings'].str.contains('A'))[0]:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 299 µs per loop

%timeit df.loc[df['strings'].str.contains('A').cumsum().astype(bool)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 516 µs per loop
```

I initially misread - the below keeps the row with the `match` and the one immediately below, keeping in case useful for anyone: To select ALL lines that match and all lines immediately succeeding those, you could use `.shift()` and `pd.Index.union` along these lines:

```
df.loc[df[df['strings'].str.contains(test_string)].index.union(df[df['strings'].str.contains(test_string).shift().fillna(False)].index)]
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'), 100), columns=['strings'])
df.head()

  strings
0       B
1       A
2       B
3       E
4       D
5       C
6       E
7       D
8       D
9       D

test_string = 'A'
df.loc[df[df['strings'].str.contains(test_string)].index.union(df[df['strings'].str.contains(test_string).shift().fillna(False)].index)]
```

to get:

```
   strings
1        A
2        B
11       A
12       A
13       D
18       A
19       C
36       A
37       C
42       A
43       E
44       A
45       C
51       A
52       B
56       A
57       A
58       A
59       C
62       A
63       D
69       A
70       E
73       A
74       E
96       A
97       A
98       B
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, also the "simple fix" via slicing. I'll have to decide on the most useful answer for future readers. But this is perhaps the more completionist alternative.

Comment: I guess for some reason we all expected something more complicated, or perhaps I misled everyone when coming up with a solution for an imaginary problem. But at least I answered your question!

Comment: See update for an improved solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cumsum().astype(bool)` to create a boolean selection mask:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB', 'XX', 'AA', 'AB', 'XX', 'BA', 'BB']},
                  index=[1,2]*5)

mask = df['col'].str.contains(r'XX').cumsum().astype(bool)
print(df.loc[mask])
```

yields

```
  col
1  XX
2  AA
1  AB
2  XX
1  BA
2  BB
```

This works because `cumsum` treats `True` as equal to 1 and `False` as equal to 0.

---

Alternatively, you could use [`np.flatnonzero`](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to find the *ordinal* index of the first `True` value:

```
In [73]: df.iloc[np.flatnonzero(df['col'].str.contains(r'XX'))[0]:]
Out[73]: 
  col
1  XX
2  AA
1  AB
2  XX
1  BA
2  BB
```

The works because `flatnonzero` treats `False` as equal to zero and `True` as a non-zero value.

This is a bit faster for large DataFrames since it avoids cumulative summing and
conversion of ints back too boolean values:

```
In [84]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB', 'XX', 'AA', 'AB', 'XX', 'BA', 'BB']}, index=[1,2]*5)

In [85]: df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [86]: %timeit df.loc[df['col'].str.contains(r'XX').cumsum().astype(bool)]
10 loops, best of 3: 46 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit df.iloc[np.flatnonzero(df['col'].str.contains(r'XX'))[0]:]
10 loops, best of 3: 43.5 ms per loop
```

---

Both of the methods above avoid reliance on the index *value*, just in case the index is non-unique.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Disregard, I misread and thought you were trying to discard every row preceding ones with matches. Anyways, if that is what you want, this is your code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
test_string = "myUniqueMatch"

mask = df["Column"].str.contains(test_string).shift(-1).fillna(False)
newDf = df.loc[~mask]
```